# error: package com.moengage.push.amp.plus does not exist

Tags: moengage

Trying to integrate MoEngage Android SDK using Java.
Documentations referred - https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403466194708-Configuring-Xiaomi-Push

Code snippet is similar to what is mentioned in the sample app. https://github.com/moengage/Android-Sample

I'm getting below errors
package `com.moengage.push.amp.plus` does not exist and
error: package MiPushHelper does not exist

[Error image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIohz.png)

No errors were expected but I got the error below:
package `com.moengage.push.amp.plus` does not exist and
error: package MiPushHelper does not exist

Comment: Please share the dependencies you have added to your project in the description.

Comment: I would recommend referring to https://github.com/moengage/React-Native-Sample-App for react-native instead of the native sample-app